# create mongodb list inside of a table

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database

I want to create a chat app.
I need to decide how my DB is gonna look like.
I a m using mongodb as a DB.

I want to have a collection named "users" which will have every user that is registered for my app.

i.e.

```
users
 - Mike
 - David
 - Adam
```

I also want to have a collection of rooms that are in my chat app.

i.e.

```
rooms
- Game of thrones
- Class of 94'
- sicence fiction
- pet lovers
```

I also want to have a collection of room with users

i.e.

```
pet lovers (room name) 
- Mike (user1)
- Dave (user2)
.....
```

I know how to represent the users and rooms in mongodb.

But any idea how to represent the "users in room" collection? it seem I need a list inside a collection (list of users in room) in addition I need to save the room name.

I want it to be easy to pull data out of this collection (i.e. remove or add user to a room / find out which room a user is chatting in...)

also, if someone has a better suggestion to represent this data - feel free...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a `users` array that contains IDs of users in a given room to `room` document, so the rooms collection will something looks like:

```
[
  {
    "_id":"...",
    "roomName":"Game of Thrones",
    //...
    "users":[
       "userId1",
       "userId2",
       //...
       "userIdn"
    ]
  }, {
    "_id":"...",
    "roomName":"the secret zone",
    //...
    "users":[
       "userId2",
       //...
    ]
  }
]
```

then, when a user join a room `R`, you'll add his ID to `R.users` array. and remove it when he left.

by the way, I think defining some schema model with [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html) may be helpful

Comment: I am using mongoose. can you please add how can I create the model you suggested in mongoose? also - won't this model be problemtic when I want to see per user, which rooms is he chatting in? how can I query this?

Comment: check this guide [Mongoose Schemas](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html), in the implementation that I've suggested I suppose that a user can be in more than one room at a time.
and to get in which room/rooms the user is logged, without checking all the rooms documents, you can similarly add a `rooms` array to the `UserSchema`, that you update when ever he enter/leave some room :)

Comment: thanks but won't that be redanant? to save the same data in 2 diffrent collection? beacuse then I could get which rooms a user is in by : 1. checking all the rooms and 2. checking the usersschema for certian user.

Comment: yes it is redundant, but it could be faster; 
- if you have hundreds of rooms. you want to check in which one he is, instead of querying all the 100 rooms, you'll just check his `rooms` array.
- if you have thousands of user; you want to get the list of user in a room (about a dozen), instead of querying each user, then checking his rooms array, you'll just check the room `users`